# How to save json response and result in an excel sheet

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, data-driven-tests

I want to save each json response to the respective input (in the same excel file which I have used as input file for data driven test testing.) in the each input row as shown below .Can anyone please help me in this, i am using SOAP UI PRO. I am new to groovy scripting. whether can it be done using some test steps?

empolyeeName    output json Result
abcd        PASS

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a data sink. soapUI Pro comes with [one of these built in](https://www.soapui.org/docs/data-driven-tests/datasink-teststep.html), which can be configured to write to Excel, CSV or databases.

For example:
[image]

If you're using the same Excel as both your data source and data sink, you may need to do some testing to see if there's any contention.

Comment: but by using data sink option it will not save in json format. Can you please provide some more details or any groovy script to write json to input excel sheet

Comment: You can still do it with the built-in data sink test step. The response is just another custom property which you can refer to in your configuration as above.